# Threejs raycast not returning the correct point

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, three.js, raycasting

I have a JSON string that I'm reading from, and it has a list of x and y coords I'm using for the positions of some BoxGeometry.

I have a raycaster setup so that when I mouse over the mesh with the voxels, it returns of position the raycast hit. Then it rounds the hit point x and z to the nearest int, and gets the additional data from the JSON string for that x and z and displays it in a popup.

My issue is that the raycast says it's hitting stuff when it's over blank areas, and doesn't say it's hitting them mesh when it is over some of the mesh areas.

You can see a demo here: https://sleepy-bayou-1572.herokuapp.com/ (it can take about 20 seconds to load the visualizer, it has standard orbit mouse controls).

And here is the source for the browser side javascript: https://sleepy-bayou-1572.herokuapp.com/bundle.js (the THREE stuff is at the bottom of the file)

In the demo you can see it's showing thepopup when your mouse is not over the mesh, and in some spots it won't show when it is.

My one guess is that the raycast isn't casting in the correct direction, but I don't know of any way to check where it's casting as I'm still new to the raycasting stuff.

**Update #1**

The answer by @6502 was partially the issue, when I fixed that I started getting the correct values.

Now I have a new issue with it, I just fixed the CSS on the page so that the canvas for three is placed below that header, I changed all references to `window.innerHeight` to a variable with the height minus the navbar size (52px) and it's way off again. It looks like something isn't being adjusted to the height correctly.

**Update #2**

Is it possible to set the aspect ratio, normalized mouse coordinates, etc to use the size of the `renderer.domElement`? I'm creating this in an instance where the page size and layout will probably change a bit, so it would be good to not have to manually set the offset of the window each time.

This is probably going to be embedded in an iframe so this would be important.

Comment: Just noticed the heroku example had crashed, it's fixed now

Comment: This is a very interesting question, but without the relevant code in the post itself, it is not suitable for Stack Overflow. Would you consider updating it to be more self-contained, so that future readers might benefit? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have a typo in the normalized mouse coordinates computation (uses `windowHeight` twice instead of width and height):

```
function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    mouse.x = (event.clientX / windowHeight) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = -(event.clientY / windowHeight) * 2 + 1;

}
```

the code should be instead

```
mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
```

Comment: good call! that fixed it partially. Check the edit on the question I'm just adding for the rest of the issue I'm having

Comment: just added additional details to the main question